# Deleting Duplicates From CSV File Wtih Multi-Columns Based On A Specific Column

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with 3 columns (phonenumber, name, amount). I need to delete any duplicate rows based strictly on the phonenumber column.

example:

number      name          amount
5555551212  John Smith    $50.00
5555551212  John Smith   $100.00
5555551515  Jane Doe     $125.00
5555551515  Steve Doe    $125.90

result:

5555551212  John Smith   $50.00
5555551515  Jane Doe    $125.00

The code I have finds and deletes duplicates but all 3 columns have to be the same and that's not what I need.

Here's my code. Thanks!

```
$rows = [];
if (($handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    list($phone, $name, $amount) = $data;
    $phone = str_replace(['(',')','-'], '', $phone);
    $amount = str_replace(['$'], "", $amount);
    $amount = sprintf('$%.2f', $amount);

    // you can build a new array with the updated values
    $rows[] = [$phone, $name, $amount];
    // or output directly
    //echo "$phone | $name | $amount";
}
fclose($handle);
}

// if you want to save the destination with the updated information...
$fd = fopen($file_tmp, 'w');

// save the column headers
fputcsv($fd, array('number', 'name', 'amount'));


foreach ($rows as $fields) {
fputcsv($fd, $fields);
}

fclose($fd);


// array to hold all "seen" lines
$lines = array();

// open the csv file
if (($handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r")) !== false) {
// read each line into an array
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
    // build a "line" from the parsed data
    $line = join(",", $data);

    // if the line has been seen, skip it
    if (isset($lines[$line])) continue;

    // save the line
    $lines[$line] = true;
}
fclose($handle);
}

// build the new content-data
$contents = '';
foreach ($lines as $line => $bool) $contents .= $line . "\r\n";

// save it to a new file
file_put_contents($file_tmp, $contents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid duplicate column values in the same loop you're building the array simply by tracking `$phone` in its own array or searching the entire `$rows` array each time. The former option will be more efficient.

### Example

```
$rows = $phones = [];
if (($handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        list($phone, $name, $amount) = $data;
        $phone = str_replace(['(',')','-'], '', $phone);
        $amount = str_replace(['$'], "", $amount);
        $amount = sprintf('$%.2f', $amount);
        
        // track unique phone numbers here
        if (isset($phones[$phone])) {
            // it's a duplicate so just ignore the entire row
            continue;
        }
        // otherwise it's a new phone number so store it
        $phones[$phone] = true;
        $rows[] = [$phone, $name, $amount];
    }

    fclose($handle);

}
```

Comment: Excellent! Works great. Thank you very much!